Scope error in GDScript within the same function
I'm making a chess game, and ran into this;
func _ready() -> void:
    var x = Vector2(10,0)
    var y = Vector2(0,10)
    var white_sqaure = ImageTexture.create_from_image(Image.load_from_file("res://w_square.png"))
    var black_sqaure = ImageTexture.create_from_image(Image.load_from_file("res://b_sqaure.png"))
    for i in range(1,9):
        for j in range(1,9):
            print(i,j)
            var square = Node2D.new()
            square.set_position(i*x + j*y)
            self.add_child(square)
            var sprite = Sprite2D.new()
            if (i+j)%2 == 0:
                sprite.texture = black_square
                pass
            else:
                sprite.texture = white_square
                pass
            square.add_child(sprite)
    pass # Replace with function body.

Errors
Line 18:Identifier "black_square" not declared in the current scope.
Line 21:Identifier "white_square" not declared in the current scope.
Edit
I fixed the issue by using the load function:
func _ready() -> void:
    var ws = load("res://w_square.png")
    var bs = load("res://b_sqaure.png")

But I'm not really sure what is going on and why the previous method doesn't work. Any tips?

I am guessing these are warnings and not errors?  I have found that gdscript does not like variables being initialized outside of their very specific scope - in this case outside of your loop. but it also feels wasteful to redeclare them on every iteration. I usually ignore these warnings, but if you move the declarations inside the loop the warnings should disappear.

I would love to connect. I am actually having some trouble with where the board appears on the window.

Probably the easiest would be to join the bacon and games discord - a friendly small godot dev server. Here is an invite link, or just look up bacon and games on youtube (or probably search discord for the same name); https://discord.gg/v3MXkn4r
